# Remove small objects in a mask and generate a new binary mask out of for loop

Tags: label, generate

I appreciate your help;

This part of the code allows me to plot what I want but I need to assign the outcome(a binary image with >500 area objects) to a variable for further processing

```
Improved_label = np.zeros_like(label_image)

#props = regionprops(label_image)

for R in regionprops(label_image):
    if R.area > 500:
        # draw the region (I'm sure there's a more efficient way of doing it)
        for c in R.coords:  
            Improved_label[c[0], c[1]] = 1

#Improved_labe1 = Improved_label > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is something wrong with the name "improved" at the beginning of the variable name(not sure why). but anyhow, here are two solutions for this issue. I hope this will be helpful for people with the background in Matlab:

-------------Option A--------------

```
label2_test = np.zeros_like(label_image)

for R in regionprops(label_image):
    if R.area > 1000:
        # draw the region (I'm sure there's a more efficient way of doing it)
        for c in R.coords:  
            label2_test[c[0], c[1]] = 1

label2_test = label2_test > 0

plt.imshow(labe2_test)
```

----------------Option B-----------------

```
from skimage import morphology
labe1_improved = morphology.remove_small_objects(label_image, min_size=1000)
```